# How can I fix this bad Merge in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, merge, branching-and-merging

[image: Gprah capture]

I have this scenario. First of nothing, yes I know, we are working directly on the trunk, that will change tomorrow (literally).

This guy merged code and walked over everybody else code. I'd like to bring up the 1625 REV. Is there a way? I don't care losing what comes next, he deserves to do his work again.

I was thinking doing a branch from 1625. But what would happen if I want to merge with default later? Can I just stay with everything that would be in the new branch?

Comment: Don't have knee jerk reaction against everyone working in the default named branch. Changing that wouldn't have changed what happened. The branch name is just a label.

Comment: Whatever strategy you choose, be clear on this: There's no need to throw anything away just because someone merged an old branch to trunk. The guy may have violated your group's workflow, but (providing the content of the merged revisions is good) there's nothing problematic here as far as mercurial is concerned. There _is_ no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically like this: check out the good version, merge the other head, revert to the good version, commit.

```
hg up -C <good>
hg merge <bad>
hg revert -r <good> --all
hg resolve -m #if necessary
hg ci -m kill-merge
hg diff -r <good> #should be empty
```

Comment: So, having my working directory in the good Rev (1625), I merge the bad one (1634)?

Comment: Yes, you're merging in the bad revision and throwing it's changes away (revert)

Comment: Yes, there's nothing to merge: If you merge a revision A with its descendant B, you just get B.

Comment: Why do we need merge good revision with bad?  Why not start from `hg revert -r <good> --all` on the tip (bad) revision?

Comment: Regarding "nothing to merge": My bad. Unfortunately, hg refuses to create this kind of merges (although it can be tricked into it). The easiest solution would be to make some minor change you need to do anyway, commit this on top of <good> and then proceed like I said.

Comment: This solution was correct, but I did a few changes. First I was trying to merge with an incorrect revision, after finding the right one, everything worked fine. I didn't need to revert, and when conflicts appeared I just took the good rev. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this recipe:

1. Clone your `repo` to `repo-clone`.
2. Update `repo-clone` to good revision.
3. Update `repo` to tip revision.
4. Remove all except .hg from `repo`.
5. Copy all except .hg from `repo-clone` to `repo`.
6. Commit in `repo` with `hg ci -A -m 'Backout bad merges'`.

The last command will add all untracked files and forget all missing files before commit.  With this recipe you'll get exactly the same state of working directory as in the good revision.